# Multilevel nav menu Hover issue

Tags: css, navigation, navbar, submenu, multi-level

I have my nav working almost exactly how I want it.  The only issue left I can't seem to figure out is this little arrow image I use on a subnav which indicates it contains another level subnav.

```
ul#css3menu ul span {
    background-image: url("images/arrowsub.png");
    padding-right: 28px;
}
ul#css3menu ul span:hover {
    background-image: url("images/arrowsubhover.png");
    padding-right: 28px;
}
```

When you hover over each subnav with an arrow, it loads a different color arrow image to maintain contrast with the background color that changes on hover.
Problem is when you hover over the next level subnav, the arrow switches back while the background color remains changed (as it should). 

Why does the background color of the parent li not lose its hover rules but the arrow does?
you can see the behavior and code with this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eb96A/)

Comment: thanks for the edit.  i'll space the code like that in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it is better to assign the hover state on the main container of the list item rather than just target the specific element within your menu list item. In your case change your line 196 on js fiddle to `.submenu li:hover span` . Even if you move a level deep to access the child menu item, you are by default still hovering over the parent element.

Plus it is good practice not to use IDs when styling. IDs are usually reserved for Javascript.

Comment: I couldn't get anything to work with `.submenu` but the `li:hover span` portion of your selector gave me an idea and I got it to work by changing line 196 to `ul#css3menu ul li:hover span`

Comment: oh man, and this also fixed the issue i was having in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898462/conditionally-style-an-element-based-on-whether-it-contains-a-particular-child-e) which I worked around with padding and margin.  now I can eliminate that code. sweet!

Comment: hard to say who should get credit for the accepted answer.  the submenu suggestion didn't seem to work (could be my fault not implementing it properly) but you were correct about styling the hovered `li` instead of the `span`

Comment: The reason why it didn't work is because you have used an ID in line 192 to style you span and ID will always override a class. If you change line 192 to .submenu ul span, then it would work. I would recommend you reading this article http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Comment: i don't follow. The way I read line 192 (`ul#css3menu ul span`) is that I am styling all of the 'span's within a nested `ul` of all `ul`s with the id `#css3menu`.  that id is the is id of the entire nav system which is much larger than the single tab in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eb96A/). I tried substituting `.submenu` on line 192 and the result didn't work.

Comment: I think I might be confusing you even further. I made the changes that I was talking about on codepen http://codepen.io/nighrage/pen/kJnCH/. Check line 192  for the changes I was talking about.

Comment: aha, yes. I see it now. Thank you.  I will try to style more classes and be much more conscious of inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the rule that affects the background color on hover is `ul#css3menu ul li:hover>a`

Since `ul#css3menu ul li:hover` detects hovering over *any* `li` element that is a child of `ul#css3menu ul`, and the 2nd-level submenu also consists of `li`s, the hover state for the 1st-level `li` is maintained when you hover over the 2nd-level `li` because the original rule is still in effect (since it is active when you hover over *any* child `li`, including the 2nd-level `li`s).

When `ul#css3menu ul li:hover` is true the CSS style is subsequently applied to the direct child `a` (rather than applied to the `li`s) to give you the full rule of `ul#css3menu ul li:hover>a`. This confused me too for a while because the detection happens separately from the application of the styles. Hope this helps.

Comment: I follow you.  that completely explains why the button remains in its hover state even when hovering the second level.  Oh snap! and now I see why this explanation also explains why changing line 196 to `ul#css3menu ul li:hover span` fixes my issue. I was only styling `span`s in a hover state and so I wasn't hovering a `span` in the 2nd level `li` so I was losing my arrow.  now that I am styling the `span` of a hovered `li`, since I am still hovering a `li` I don't lose the arrow.  is that correct?  I hope so.  I think I'm starting to get a handle on this css stuff! woohoo!